# Convert from SQL to Criteria hibernate

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Im a little new to Hibernate Criteria.

I have the following tables :

**Player**(idPlayer, key2, fullname)

**Team**(idTeam, key2, name)

Im trying to write the following sql Query using Hibernate Criteria

Select * from Player p, Team t Where p.key2=t.key2;

the team.hbm.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class table="TEAM">
    <id name="idTeam" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="IDTEAM" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="key2" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="KEY2" />
    </property>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="NAME" />
    </property>
</class>
```

the player.hbm.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class table="PLAYER">
    <id name="idPlayer" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="IDPLAYER" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="key2" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="KEY2" />
    </property>
    <property name="fullname" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
        <column name="FULLNAME" />
    </property>

       <set name="equipes" table="TEAM" inverse="false" lazy="true">
        <key>
            <column name="IDTEAM" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Package.Team" />
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can I do that please ?

Comment: please post your entity classes. what have you written so far?

Comment: @Apostolos i have added the hbm.xml correspanding files. please check the post again

Comment: I am not sure that you can do cartesian join with the Criteria API. You should use HQL to achieve that and it is as easy as sql